# How works intruction mod in the vhdl program?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I just have one doubt with the following program:

```
process(clk)
        variable cuenta : integer range 0 to 255 := 0;
    begin
        if clk = '1' and clk'event then
            cuenta := (cuenta +1) mod 256;
            if cuenta < D then
                S <= '1';
            else
                S <= '0';
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
```

On statement `cuenta:= (cuenta+1) mod 256`, the value of `cuenta` reaches the value of 255 ? , I mean `cuenta` it is not just 0 all the time ? `D` is just a value between 0 a 255.
Thanks and I hope someone could help me with this maybe simple question.

Comment: That's not a program nor a VHDL design unit, it's a process statement without context. If you were to provide a [mcve] and also simulated it you would find that a) cuenta *reaches the value 255* and b) *is not just 0 all the time*.  Should your simulator not support displaying the value of variables, you could make cuenta a signal or [define a signal the value of cuenta is assigned to before `end process`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAEq3.jpg).

Comment: change `cuenta` from `variable` to `signal`. It's a clocked/registered signal, so define it as such. using variables this way is asking for problems.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your code with a testbench, if you run this you will be able to tell that cuenta just gets 1 added to it then module devised by 256. I stopped the increment, now it's just a signal driven in.

Getting more information may help actually solve your problem. Hopefully what I have added helps though.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;


entity cuenta is
port(
    clk       : in std_logic;
    reset     : in std_logic;
    D         : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    cuenta    : in std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);
    modulo_in : in std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);
    S         : out std_logic
);

end cuenta;

architecture behav of cuenta is

    signal cuenta_q : std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);

begin
 process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
           if reset = '1' then
              cuenta_q <= (others => '0');
              S <= '0';
           elsif reset = '0' then
              cuenta_q <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(cuenta + 1) mod unsigned(modulo_in));
              if cuenta_q < D then
                 S <= '1';
              else
                 S <= '0';
              end if;
           end if;
       end if;
    end process;

end behav;


library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity tb_cuenta is
end tb_cuenta;



architecture tb of tb_cuenta is

   signal clk       : std_logic := '1';
   signal reset     : std_logic := '1';
   signal D         : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
   signal cuenta    : std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);
   signal modulo_in : std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);
   signal S         : std_logic;

begin

    D         <=  x"F0";
    cuenta    <= "000100000";
    modulo_in <= "100000000";

    clk   <= not clk after 50 fs;
    reset <= '0' after 200 fs;

ceunta_inst : entity work.cuenta 
   port map(
        clk => clk,
    reset => reset,
    D => D,
    cuenta => cuenta,
    modulo_in => modulo_in,
    S => S
   );

end tb;
```